# I am doing ecommerce site using django framework. I want post as well as get in same view as I need to add brand and list from the same page

Tags: python, django

[This is how my template looks like. Here I need to add brand and list them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKBAn.png)

Comment: better you use django-oscar or django-saleor

Comment: May I kindly suggest you read [ask] and [mcve] ???

Answer (score 3):

You can use `django.views.generic` to display brand list and for redirect to same page, the post view should return to the same page, use below code to redirect to same page..

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

Please let me know if its working correctly..